# Powershell JSON object to HTML table and add it to the value of another JSON object

Tags: html, json, powershell

I have following JSON object which is dynamically created and can contain special characters in the names e.g. O'Brian in Last Name and special characters in Notes.

```
$jsonData = @"
{
        "ReqId": 37,
        "First Name": "John",
        "Middle Name": "",
        "Last Name": "O'Brian",
        "Preferred Name": "John",
        "Date": "04/28/2021 05:00:00",
        "Email": "test@xyz.com",
        "Notes": "This is a note with Special characters"
}
"@ | ConvertTo-Json;
```

I want to use this JSON data and convert it to HTML table format.
Then pass this HTML data as a value of the key in another JSON object which will then be sent to API.

```
$convData = ConvertTo-Html -InputObject ($jsonData);
$apiJson = @"
    {
        "Title" : "This is Test",
        "Description" : "This is Test Description.<br ><br /> $convData"
    }
    "@
```

$apiJson needs to be valid JSON so that API can parse it as a JSON object successfully.

I tried ConvertTo-HTML method but it is not working and gives empty table. Also I want just `<table>...</table>` part and need to remove other tags.

```
{
    "Test" : "This is Test",
    "description" : "This is Test.<br > <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//E
N"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/x
html"> <head> <title>HTML TABLE</title> </head><body> <table> <colgroup><col/></colgroup> <tr>
<th>*</th></tr> <tr><td>539</td></tr> </table> </body></html>"
}
```

Need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change `ConvertTo-Json` to `ConvertFrom-Json` - You want to convert the json to an object which can be converted into html table
2. Add the `-Fragment` switch to the `ConvertTo-Html` in order to generate only the HTML table

_

```
$jsonData = @'
{
        "ReqId": 37,
        "First Name": "John",
        "Middle Name": "",
        "Last Name": "O'Brian",
        "Preferred Name": "John",
        "Date": "04/28/2021 05:00:00",
        "Email": "test@xyz.com",
        "Notes": "This is a note with Special characters"
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$convData = $jsonData | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
$apiJson = @"
    {
        "Title" : "This is Test",
        "Description" : "This is Test Description.<br ><br /> $convData"
    }
"@
```